# How to restrict my scale between two lines?

Tags: transforms

Im a newbie to blender so this might be a simple fix.

Im trying to scale between two lines.
See attached pic of cube.
[image]

This was created by ctrl+R to add a loop cut then ctrl+B to get the line above and below. I then select the center line hit Ctrl+S to scale. Instead of scaling the line in between the two lines I scale the whole new rectangle. (see below pic)

[image: Here is what's happening at the moment]

What I want to do is scale in between the two lines. see 2d version below of what I want to achieve.
[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: If my answer solved your question mark it as answered please so future users will find a solution :). If it did not solve it ill try again to solve it for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MRxx, you have proportional editing enabled.
With this setting, you edit the surrounding faces as well, not just your edges.
You can quick-toggle it by pressing your O key.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, Thank you very much, sorry, beginners mistake.